# Show that polynomial is reducible

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials

Show that $p(x)$ = $x^3 + 3x^2 + 2x + 4$ is reducible in $\mathbb{Z}$$/$$7$$\mathbb{Z}$

Is the approach for this to factor it and then find a root? I'm a little confused on how to start. Any tips appreciated.

Comment: If if factors, then at least one of the factors will have to be linear, since the sum of their degree is $3$. So you can just look for roots -- there are only 7 possibilities.

Answer (score 3):

Since $p$ has degree $3$, it is reducible iff it has a root. Since $\mathbb Z / 7 \mathbb Z$ is a finite field, we can test every element to see if it's a root or not.

Comment: Oh I see. Plug in everything from 0 to 6 into p(x) and check to see if it is 0 mod 7?

Comment: @user201917 Exactly!

Comment: What happens if $p(x)$ has degree higher than 3?

Comment: @user201917 This method becomes insufficient. In general, a polynomial of degree $> 3$ can be reducible without having roots. Take the product of two irreducible polynomials of degree $2$ for example.

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

\begin{align}p(x) &= x^3 + 3x^2 + 2x + 4\\
& = x^3 - 4x^2 + 2x + 4\\
& = x^3 - 2x^2 - 2x^2 + 4x - 2x + 4\\
& = x^2(x - 2) - 2x(x - 2) - 2(x - 2)\\
& = (x^2 - 2x - 2)(x - 2).
\end{align}

Comment: how did you know where to manipulate it?

Comment: Are you wondering how I went from the first line to the second line, or from the second line to the third line?

Comment: I mean in more of a general sense. How did you get the intuition of only taking mod 7 for the x^2 term so that you could eventually manipulate the (x-2) out of all of them? Is there a method to this or just playing around with the numbers?

Comment: Since it's given that $p$ is reducible, by reducing only the coefficient of $x^2$ to $-4$, I know that I can factor $p$ into factors where the non-leading terms have coefficients $2$ or $-2$. That gave me the idea to break down the terms from the second line to get the expression in the third line, which makes the factorization easier to obtain.